# Count words from many .txt files

Tags: python, word-count

I want to show every word that appears in each `.txt` file and the amount of times it occurs. Here is my code:

```
listtxt = ['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt',...]
output = open('dictionary.txt','w')
d = {}

for i in listtxt:
   with open(i,'r') as file:
     data = file.read()

     for char in '-.,;”“':
         data=data.replace(char,' ')

     data = data.lower()
     word_list = data.split()

     for word in word_list:
         d[word] = d.get(word,0) +1

     for words, count in d.items():
         output.write(('{} : {} \n'.format(words, count)))

output.close()
```

When I run it, it appears that the words and the number of occurrences appear separately, meaning it did not check the words that were in the previous file. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: I do not think `data = data.lower()` and everything after it must be in the `for char in '-.,;”“'` loop.

Comment: You might want to use `string.punctuation` (after importing the `string` library first) instead of `'-.,;”“'` 

EG: `for char in string.punctuation:`

Comment: @DyZ I have some tab wrong when i post this question, i've just edited it

Comment: @Jono2906 it worked,ty. But it does not fix the problem

Comment: Just was a suggestion for you.

Comment: Python intentation is four spaces, see PEP 8 (I think). Now, this isn't the required MCVE, as such, your question is off-topic. However, I suggest you just research how to step through a program with a debugger, it's probably much faster than extracting an MCVE.

Comment: _"it appears that"_ - Please include an MCVE.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple indentation error. Last loop (for words, count in d.items()) needs to be outside the first loop (for i in listtxt).

Tabs matter in python.